# What are the effects of storing drinking water in a copper container?

Tags: benefits, metal, water-filter-purifier, experiment

I recently learned that Ayurveda recommends storing drinking water in copper containers for positive health benefits.

Upon my simple experimentation, I've noticed the following effects:

**Water Type** : activated carbon filtered drinking water

**Duration of storage**: 8 hours

The taste of the water changed, it tasted more metallic. I think this is because of the increase of dissolved copper in the water.

If I'm drinking 4-5 liters of water per day, would that be still under the safe limit of 2 mg/day? [ref 2](http://www.who.int/water_sanitation_health/dwq/chemicals/copper.pdf) Note: I don't have any apparatus to measure the copper content in the water.

I've researched a bit and found that it does have some positive effects on killing some microbes such as bacteria [ref 1](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3312355/). Note: I'm not able to deduce any conclusion about the increase in copper content from this paper even though the author said it is "within the permissible limits."

I would like to know more about the studies related to this claim and I'm really interested to know about the side effects.

Comment: Ayurveda is a system of traditional medicine developed during antiquity and the medieval period, and as such is comparable to pre-modern Chinese and European systems of medicine. Although laboratory experiments suggest it is possible that some substances in Ayurveda might be developed into effective treatments, there is no evidence that any are effective as currently proffered. Ayurveda medicine is considered **pseudoscientific**

Comment: @JJosaur This question is not about Ayurveda! This is about storing water in copper container.